# Getting 500 Internal Server Error from request

Tags: python, python-requests

Long story short i'm making script for parsing sankakucomplex in search of pictures and downloading them. And everything until this function goes fine

```
def download_image_from_link(link, auth, number):
    url = f"https:{link}"
    bruh = requests.get(url)
    with open(f"images/{auth}/image{number}.png", "wb") as im:
        im.write(bruh.content)
```

{link} is something like //v.sankakucomplex.com/data/sample/a5/dc/sample-a5dcd9f21fc80b6bfe5acfa74c3bd936.jpg?e=1648321131&expires=1648321131&m=JqNaW8AUSE-G-jyihn0uiQ&token=hLsB-lYp7bQhgUbkLsZScpch1DBX6JQoFh4T-CglAKA

{auth} and {number} is not important

It just downloads all the puctires from array that i received from other inconsiderable in this situation functions.

And half of links to images starts with http://s. and other half is http://v.

So the thing is when it downloads http://v. files everything is fine, but in when it downloads http://s. it receives

```
b'<html>\r\n<head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<center><h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n'
```

Here is the safest links that i could find if you need to check:

for //s. link

https://chan.sankakucomplex.com/ru/post/show/30856755

for //v. link (requests for //beta. doesnt work too)

https://beta.sankakucomplex.com/ru/post/show/30856755

Comment: For one, you should call `bruh.raise_for_status()` so you'd get an exception instead of writing a 500 Error response to your file. Beyond that, why the server returns 500 is not in our hands.

Comment: Yeah it would work, but the main question is how can i download image without getting status 500?

Comment: That's up to you to figure out. Chances are Sankakucomplex needs some cookies, or a proper origin header, or maybe your link is just malformed and doesn't work at all. (You should verify whether you can find the same image in the browser, and whether the link you generate is exactly the same.)

Comment: Tested in postman. Just add `User-Agent` header

Comment: I actually had User-Agent in my headers and also got authorisation with cookies, but forgot to put it in requests.get stupid me. Thanks a lot!